# When the client open the webapp, how to restore his last state with router-ui?

Tags: angular-ui-router, state, reload

I use router-ui for my angular single page

I hear the $stateChangeSuccess event to store in localStorage the current state and his params :

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    localStorage.lastState = toState.name;
    localStorage.lastStateParams = JSON.stringify($stateParams);
});
```

My question is :
When the client open the webapp, I want to restore his personnal last state but where can I put this code ?

```
$state.go(localStorage.lastState, JSON.parse(localStorage.lastStateParams));
```

// UPDATE 
Actually i put this code in $stateChangeSuccess event like this :

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    if (toState.name !== 'welcome') {
        localStorage.lastState = toState.name;
        localStorage.lastStateParams = JSON.stringify($stateParams);
    }

    if (toState.name !== localStorage.lastState) {
        $state.go(localStorage.lastState, JSON.parse(localStorage.lastStateParams));
    }
});
```

The problem with this solution is the process is like this at opening app :

- localhost (user open the app)
- localhost/#/welcome ( because the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome') proc before the $stateChangeSuccess event)
- and then : localhost/#/articles/423 (on $stateChangeSuccess event)

So i'm sure i do bad, someone know the good method ?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

As always the solution is always easier than you think !

In my main controller :

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    // Timeout is required because the document.location.hash is not upadated immediatly
    $timeout(function() { 
        localStorage.hash = document.location.hash.substr(1);
    }, 100);
});
```

At end of my routes :

```
// Default
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(localStorage.hash || '/welcome');
```